# Error when using a custom function to sort a vector of arrays

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, comparison, stdarray

This is my code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<array>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool compareel (int a[], int b[])
{
    return (a[2] < b[2]);
}

int main ()
{
    
  vector < array < int, 3 >> edges = { {1, 2, 3}, {2, 2, 34}, {3, 0, 0} };
  
  sort (edges.begin (), edges.begin () + 3,compareel);

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    cout << edges[i][2] << ' ';

  return 0;
}
```

The Code seems to have problem passing the array as argument to compareel(), I've tried different methods of passing the array but nothing seems to work.

Compile error:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/predefined_ops.h:143:18: error: cannot convert ‘std::array’ to ‘int*’ in argument passing
```

Comment: The error message should be pretty self-explanatory: the function should have parameters of type `std::array<int,3> const&` , not parameters of type `int*`

Comment: @fabian: Someone new to C++ might not understand where the `int*` is

Answer (score 3):

In this function

```
bool compareel (int a[], int b[])
{
    return (a[2] < b[2]);
}
```

the parameters are adjusted by the compiler to the type `int *`. That is the above function is equivalent to

```
bool compareel (int *a, int *b)
{
    return (a[2] < b[2]);
}
```

But the class template `std::array` does not have such an implicit conversion.

So you need to declare the function like

```
bool compareel ( const std::array<int, 3> &a, const std::array<int, 3> &b )
{
    return (a[2] < b[2]);
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

bool compareel ( const std::array<int, 3> &a, const std::array<int, 3> &b )
{
    return a[2] < b[2];
}

int main ()
{
    std::vector<std::array < int, 3>> edges = 
    { 
        { 1, 2, 3 }, { 2, 2, 34 }, { 3, 0, 0 } 
    };
  
    std::sort( std::begin( edges ), std::end( edges ), compareel );

    for ( const auto &item : edges )
    {
        std::cout << item[2] << ' ';
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 3 34
```

Comment: @Phy_student  You can select the answer as the best and your reputation will be increased apart from my up-vote.